# How to handle Currency Conversion in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot, value-objects, clean-architecture

**Short Version:**
What do you think is the best option for a Value Object that needs to access currency conversion rates in the database? 
ex:

`Invoice.Amount = Invoice.Amount.toCurrency('CAD')`

**Long Version:**
I have a Value Object called `InvoiceAmount` and it has a method, `toCurrency`, that will convert the invoice amount to a specified currency.  I'd like to reuse this currency conversion logic because I know I'm going to need it in other bounded contexts(e.g. `SalesOrderAmount`, `FreightCost`, etc.).  My first thought was to create a `Money` object in a SharedKernel and then have `SalesOrderAmount`, `FreightCost` and `InvoiceAmount` inherit from `Money`.  The `toCurrency`would be implemented in the `Money` class so it is only in one place.  This sounds ok to me but maybe there is a better way.  Now the problem I have is that in my system the currency conversion rates are stored in the database so I need a repository to access conversion rates in order for `Money` to implement `toCurrency`.  I'm pretty sure DDD says not to call Repositories in Entities or Value Objects so I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve this.  I was thinking of using a Domain Service to actually do the currency conversion and `Money` would just call the Domain Service, however, I'm not sure if DDD considers this a good option either.  Maybe I need to inject the Domain Service into each Aggregate Root (`SalesOrder`, `Invoice` and `Shipment`) so I can inject that into each Money value object so it can in turn do the currency conversion.  What do you think?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm pretty sure DDD says not to call Repositories in Entities or Value Objects

Keep on that, it's a good rule. It will keep your model clean and pure.

> I  was thinking of using a Domain Service to actually do the currency conversion

I think this is the way to go. However, you should try to design your model according to the real world. Who is responsible in the financial world with money conversions? A Bank or an Exchange point (I don't know how exactly are they called in your country).

So, my suggestion is to define a Domain interface implemented in the Infrastructure (i.e. `MoneyExchangeService`) that has a single method: `convertAmount`. You call it in the Application layer and pass the result to your `Account aggregate` method as arguments. This will keep the responsibilities to where they belong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I guess I'm still stuck on my Money Value object having a toCurrency method.  If I take your approach, I could not have a toCurrency method and I would have to move the currency conversion to the UseCase/Application layer.  I was hoping to come up with a solution that could keep the currency conversion in the Money.toCurrency method.

Comment: I have a similar problem with converting Units of Measure (e.g. LB to KG, IN to CM) in which the conversion factors are stored in the database.  I have a Value Object for FreightUnits and I have a method FreightUnits.convertUOM that will convert from pounds to kilograms for example.  I feel like this simple conversion logic is too low level for the UseCase/Application layer.  Am I incorrect in thinking this way?

Comment: @TonyRaimo I'm suggesting that the service  would be a Domain service with the implementation in the Infrastructure only if a persistence is used, otherwise the implementation is also in the Domain layer, i.e. a units converter service